# setting file size in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hello I need help setting the size of flies in a grid-view, this first set of code works

```
protected string DisplaySize(long? size)
{
    if (size == null)
        return string.Empty;
    else
    {
        if (size < 1024)
        {
            return string.Format("{0:#} bytes", size.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Format("{0:#} KB", size.Value / 1024);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add more values it dose not work I just get blank values

```
protected string DisplaySize(long? size)
{
    if (size == null)
        return string.Empty;
    else
    {
        if (size < 1024)
        {
            return string.Format("{0:#} bytes", size.Value);
        }
        else if(size < 10240)
        {
            return String.Format("{0:#} KB", (size.Value / 1024));
        }
        else if(size < 102400)
        {
            return String.Format("{0:#} MB", (size.Value / 1024 / 1024));
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Format("{0:#} GB", (size.Value / 1024 / 1024 / 1024));
        }
    }
}
```

ScreenShot Working:

[image]

ScreenShot Not working:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
           if (size < 1024)
            {
                return string.Format("{0:#} bytes", size.Value);
            }
            else if(size < 1048576)
            {
                return String.Format("{0:#} KB", (size.Value / 1024));
            }
            else if(size < 1073741824)
            {
                return String.Format("{0:#} MB", ((size.Value / 1024) / 1024));
            }
            else
            {
                return String.Format("{0:#} GB", (((size.Value / 1024) / 1024) / 1024));
            }
```

Comment: @VJ' : You are Welcome :) , I'm glad to be help of you.

Answer (score 0):

your division tehniques does not makes much sence i do not know if it will fix your issue but you may try

```
((size.Value / 1024) / 1024)
((((size.Value / 1024) / 1024)/ 1024))
```